# UIA - AutomationElement doesn't return correct name when list view changes

Tags: c#-4.0, automation, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to read the contents of a "list view" using automation. The first time I navigate to it, I'm able to go from item to item, getting the correct text for each list item. However, when I display a different screen (which is apparently reusing this display object), the text on the screen is different, but automation gets the same text as the first set. From then on I can only get the text for the first view I looked at. It's like the text is being cached and I'm only able to look at the cached view. UISpy, however, seems to grab the right values every time, and if I use it while my automation is paused, I end up getting the right values.

In my automation, I use Find to grab the header, and walk the tree to the List View and get the text for each element. I thought if you used the Current property, you got the live data. Apparently I was mistaken. How do I either refresh the tree or get the REAL data?

Comment: When you say different screen, are both screens open at the same time? Is it the same object on 2 different pages or 2 different instances of the same page? Can you use UISpy to highlight the control on the 2nd screen to ensure it's finding the visible object and not a hidden instance of the first object?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `Current` property on a certain `AutomationElement` will return its current, 'live', value. UIA will not cache anything automatically, you'll have to declare it yourself and explicitly access the `Cached` properties.

What's probably happening is that the new tree items you're seeing after selecting a different screen, are actually re-created (and that actually makes sense, UI-wise), not just *updated*. You could easily determine if this is the problem by selecting the first screen and writing down the tree items' `RuntimeId` property (you can see it in UI Spy). Then, select the second screen and check if the `RuntimeId` has changed. If it has, then it's just not the same object instance.

If this is the case, all you need to do is get the items again. It'll be easier to do this using `AutomationElement.FindAll` with a `ClassName` property condition.

Comment: Actually, when I change to the other screen, I've started from the root and navigated to the elements with the same result. I've tried searching and navigating and nothing works. I ALWAYS get the same item. Funnily enough, UISpy doesn't seem to have the same problem. I can try the FindAll option, but I'm not hopeful. For now, I'm just restarting the program before navigating to the second screen; that seems to work.